# Can someone explain what went wrong with my sticky navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried time and time again with figuring out my sticky navigation and I believe is has to do with a portion of my JavaScript. I have also included my html and css just in case there's an error there.

EDIT: I've worded the previous statement wrongly, I would like the menu to stick to top after scrolling at a set point. Once i've scrolled back up I would like it to return to that point. Thank you.

HTML Code

```
<!--Navigation Menu-->
    <div id="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#relationships">Relationships</a>
        <a href="#beauty">Beauty</a>
        <a href="#entertainment">Entertainment</a>
        <a href="#selfcare">Self Care</a>
    </div>
```

CSS Code

```
#navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}


#navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: HighTide Sans;
}

.content {
    padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
    postion: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

JS Code

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's supported by your target browsers, there is a `position: sticky;` css definition that handles this logic (mostly). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

moved your source into a fiddle, if you can tidy this up to better illustrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/n2dq9mef/

Answer (score 0):

You spelled "position" wrong in your css. It should be:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that. Unfortunately that's still not the problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Changing just that typo worked fine for me, the navbar becomes sticky. Check out this codepen with your code and some dummy content - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPVevj.

Comment: There was something wrong with my id's outside the code section I provided but once I changed what you recommended and the other mistake it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your navbar needs to have the class sticky on page load:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: HighTide Sans;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!--Navigation Menu-->
<div id="navbar" class="sticky">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#relationships">Relationships</a>
  <a href="#beauty">Beauty</a>
  <a href="#entertainment">Entertainment</a>
  <a href="#selfcare">Self Care</a>
</div>
<div style="min-height:1000px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe I worded my question wrong though. I meant sticky navigation at certain point after scrolling.